# What kind of data can i store from Facebook's graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a few questions about what data I can store from Facebook's graph api. I'm creating a react-native app that uses facebook authentication, and fetches data (specifically places and current user) from the Facebook graph api. I found the "Protect Data" section under the graph api policy pages lacking in depth, so here I am trying to gain some more knowledge on the topic. Here are my questions:

1. Can I store user the user ID fetched from the /me/ api call using a user's accesstoken in my db? If so, do I need to encrypt it in any way? I read on the api docs pages that these ID's were unique to my app and would be useless anywhere else. If this is the case I don't see the harm in storing them in my db. Is this true?
2. Can I store coordinates and names of places fetched by places search? Do these need to be encrypted.

Any help and insight on the topic is greatly appreciated.